# Swift: Why can't my iOS scanned other bluetooth devices

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, bluetooth

Now I'm currently doing an application project that needs my iPhone to scan other nearby bluetooth devices and list them out. I'm wondering is my code has any problem?

Code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    var manager: CBCentralManager!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        manager = CBCentralManager (delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }


    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {

            print("Peripheral: \(peripheral)")
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
        print("Checking")
        switch(central.state)
        {
        case.Unsupported:
            print("BLE is not supported")
        case.Unauthorized:
            print("BLE is unauthorized")
        case.Unknown:
            print("BLE is Unknown")
        case.Resetting:
            print("BLE is Resetting")
        case.PoweredOff:
            print("BLE service is powered off")
        case.PoweredOn:
            print("BLE service is powered on")
            print("Start Scanning")
            manager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
        default:
            print("default state")
        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }  
}
```

I'm using iPhone 5 (iOS 9) and I'm sure that my Bluetooth is turned on.

When I run the application in my iPhone, the console only log the following output:

```
Checking
BLE service is powered on
Start Scanning
```

But there is no Bluetooth device's name shown in the output. Even I turn on my iPad (iPad Mini 4 iOS 8) and the list still wouldn't update.

Sometimes it does scan my MacBook Pro Bluetooth and the output will have this:

```
Peripheral: <CBPeripheral: 0x14d70e00, identifier = 54738076-6C97-FD04-18CF-5E1AF6705865, name = vivien’s MacBook Pro, state = disconnected>
```

So, why is this happening? Can someone please explain to me?

Comment: If there is no app running on the ipad to act as a BLE peripheral then there will be nothing for your app to find. You can use the LightBlue app to advertise a peripheral such as a heart rate monitor

Comment: @Paulw11 as what you said, my iPhone able to scan my iPad when I add virtual peripheral in LightBlue app. If delete the virtual peripheral, then it can't scan my iPad again.
I thought that all phones, tablets are peripheral devices, aren't they? So, to enable scanning other iPhones and iPads, I need to run the LightBlue app at background?

Comment: To save battery iOS only advertises when it needs to; ie when an app is advertising a peripheral

Comment: @Paulw11 So no matter how I still need to run the LightBlue app at background, right? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Well, you need some app advertising in the background for your device to be discoverable

Comment: Is there any other way to force my app to advertise?

Comment: Your app can advertise by implementing a CBPeripheral through CBPeripheralManager.  It can do this in the background.  Then another instance of your app running on another device could discover the first device.

Comment: @Paulw11 can my app runs both? I mean act as peripheral and also central?

Comment: does it work for a while when you reset the device? There are 5Ss out there that do this when you go into the background without manually locking the screen

Answer (score 1):

case 1:
You must use GKSession to scan and connect with another iOS device,not CoreBluetooth.
case 2:
Your bluetooth device is a Bluetooth 3.0 accessory.Your iPhone can discover and show it in Setting->Bluetooth.
But this message isn't delivered to your app,so your app won't discover it.
Try again with a Bluetooth 4.0  accessory.

Comment: But even in my iPhone Setting>Bluetooth discovered list, my iPad mini and other bluetooth 4.0 devices like Nexus 5, didn't show up. 
So the problem now, I wanted to scan and list all other bluetooth devices only (no pairing). Can this be done using the GKSession you mentioned?

Comment: @vivien You can download LightBlue App in app Store.it's a great tool for CoreBluetooth debugging. GKSession is useful when you try to connect two iOS devices not all bluetooth devices.

Comment: I'd downloaded. Still only my MacBook appeared in the "peripheral nearby" list. How does a device is counted peripheral? Is it related to the peripheral thingy so that my app's scan list only shows my Macbook instead of other bluetooth devices nearby?

Comment: case1: your bluetooth device is broken.case2: your bluetooth device is already connectted to another device,so it won't  broadcast ,and you can't discover.case 3: your bluetooth don't change state to discoverable.