# How to differentiate between a device paired via Bluetooth and a device "paired" via cable using ExternalAccessory?

Tags: ios, external-accessory, mfi

I am trying to find a way to establish which of my

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories];
```

are connected via Bluetooth and which are connected via USB.

External accessory considers all devices connected using one of the above methods as "CONNECTED.

From what I've read in Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory?language=objc)

"The External Accessory framework enables your app to communicate with external hardware that is connected to an iOS-based device through the Apple Lightning or 30-pin connector, or wirelessly through Bluetooth"

(emphasis on OR)

Buuut... is there any way to differentiate between a wirelessly through Bluetooth connected device and a USB connected device using ExternalAccessory?

Answer (score 0):

I think depends on the Bluetooth type (Bluetooth 3.0, 4.0, BLE, ...)

**[External Accessory Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory)** will work with older Bluetooth 3.0 models, and accessories that have joined the apple MFi program

**[Core Bluetooth Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth)** will communicate with Bluetooth low energy and BR/EDR (“Classic”) Devices.

And, Your bluetooth device is a Bluetooth 3.0 accessory.Your iPhone can discover and show it in Setting->Bluetooth.
But this message isn't delivered to your app,so your app won't discover it.
Try again with a Bluetooth 4.0 accessory.

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34146743/6284714)